# Small LAN network with internet access at both ends

Tags: networking, router, lan

I run a small network with one ISP at the office, and a Ubiquiti wireless connection to an isolated mountaintop.  Now, we are suddenly going to get access to a second ISP at the distant location.  My IT guy is a volunteer who is not always available. Where can I turn for design info on load balancing and fallover from a single LAN to two separate ISPs, from two different locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubiquiti controllers and setup are not trivial or instinctive (says me with a Ubiquiti box in upstairs office).

To replace the volunteer IT person, you need a local technical consultant with networking skills for both design (loading and balancing) and implementation support.

This would be in addition to your own expertise and as such is another pair of hands.

The person should offer hourly services, or a reasonable standby contract for a block of services.

This kind of service does not really fit a forum like this in the sense that you may or may not get the specific assistance you need in the time frame you need.

Comment: John, I have a sophisticated Ubiquiti system with 2 Dream machines, seven radio legs, and about 40 devices over 4 venues.  I found it VERY instinctive and was able to ask for, and get, help with it when I needed.   "Hire an expert" was never an answer, and I find your "help" singularly unhelpful.  I went elsewhere and found several suggestions, without the snobbery and attitude.  I can put a load balancing router in to weigh/mix both the locally-arriving and distant IP, and assign DHCP at the office for that branch, and let the distant IP serve the Ubiquity branch.. "Thanks" anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: Please read the whole thing.

Comment: I read through everything and (with the exception of long distance isolation and connectivity) I have done this kind of thing for my customers.

Comment: I made changes to my answer so to clarify that I was primarily answer the question of replacing your volunteer person. I was not aiming anything at you at all. Nonetheless, if you wish to, you may unaccept my answer. Cheers.